# How can I fetch Facebook reactions from a closed group via Python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As an Admin of a closed Facebook group, I'm trying to fetch the reactions on the posts contained within. I've tried using the Graph API explorer but I simply cannot get it to return any results using a user token. I'm using these endpoints:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/reactions/

I've tried using the above photo reactions endpoint, and also the insights endpoint with post_reactions_like_total:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/insights#availmetrics

I've used in the address bar:

```
20728370730XXXXX_22114053XXXXXX/reactions
```

But nothing seems to work. Does anyone know the best way to go about this or what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What doesn't seem to be working? Are you getting an Exception or just unexpected output? The last I tried using facebook's api was about a year ago when they started really limiting what could be done with it amidst all of the negative PR from the Cambridge Analytica fiasco

Comment: I get a successful reply but the data fields are empty which is where the reactions should be. There's just nothing in there. And I completely agree, a lot of old documentation is completely useless so I have been struggling to find an answer..

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to pin it on that exactly, because I don't know for sure if that's the cause, tbh. However, there's a high likelihood that it could be the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use those APIs on Groups. Groups access via Apps (including APIs) were severely limited after all of the Facebook privacy issues.

The only things you can do via groups are using the [Groups API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/common-uses#getting-group-posts) which is a collection of Graph API endpoints for groups.

You can get post information and posts with personal information removed. I’m unsure if you can get reactions on the posts, but you can get the text and ID.

Comment: Well there are 3rd party services that offer this such as Zapier and Intergomat so I know this is possible. I'm just going over their free tiers which is why I'm trying to code this myself. I've successfully fetched the number of reactions from my closed group, but without personally identifying information. I had to add them as an App to the group for this to work though.

Comment: The Groups API is what you need to use then. That’s the only way to get information from a Group.

Answer (score -1):

Only the total reactions count seems to be available:

```
{group-id}/feed?fields=message,reactions.summary(1)
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/reactions says,

> for [post] nodes, /reactions doesn't return a profile except for the current user, if read with a user access token

So if you reacted to any post yourself, you should be able to get *that* reaction, with your own user token - but everything else does not seem to be exposed to you via API any more.

(Other services might have special access, or they are probably just scraping the data.)